# How to make box appear when text is entered into input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="center1">
<form>
<input type="text" class="input1" autofocus="focus"  />
</form>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="center1">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

I have added it to this JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/PDnnK/4/

As you can see there is:

INPUT FIELD
&
BOX

I want the box to appear only when text is typed in the input. How is this done?

Comment: If i knew that i wouldn't have asked. What would I be looking for to help me with this?

Comment: probably something like `onkeyup="document.getElementById('box').css.visibility = (this.value.length > 0) ? 'none' : 'block'` on the input field.

Answer (score 2):

Start the box out with `display: none`. Then, you can capture the `keypress` event for the input:

```
document.getElementById('myInput').onkeypress = function () {
  document.getElementById('myBox').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: check out: http://jsfiddle.net/PDnnK/23/ i used your help but it still didn't work. Am I using it right?

Comment: That's because your `id`s did not match (the HTML and the JavaScript). I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with jQuery:

```
$("#id-of-input").change(function() { $("#id-of-box"}.css('display', 'block'); } );
```

or change .change to .click

Answer (score 1):

Binding to "change" is usually not super-handy, since it usually doesn't fire until you tab or click away from the element.

However, polling isn't the answer either.

original answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/xNEZH/2/

super-fantastic new answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/4MhKU/1/

```
$('.input1').bind('mouseup keyup change cut paste', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var hasInput = $('.input1').val() != "";
        $('.box')[hasInput ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    }, 20);
});
```

The setTimeout is because cut and paste events fire BEFORE the text is cut or pasted.

Comment: Thanks! it works great in jsfiddle but when i use it in my code and on my browser it doesn't work. i am using the latest versions of chrome and safari. Why is this?

Comment: If he uses jQuery, which your polling function also uses, most key and mouse events are well normalized. I wouldn't hesitate to use them myself; I'm not intending to disbelieve you, but I wonder what reproducible situations (using jQuery) expose key/mouse events as unreliable?

Comment: James - two most likely reasons it doesn't work for you outside of the jsfiddle: 1. you don't have jquery sourced before you try to run this code. 2. You're not running this code ondomready.

Comment: Greg: Yeah, actually just the 'change' is silly - usually doesn't fire until after the form control loses focus (i.e., you click or tab off of it).